# Using spring schedule and changing system time in runtime

Tags: java, spring, cron, schedule

I have a spring schedule configured to run everyday at 00:01h.

```
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="bean" method="method" cron="0 1 0 * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

If I change the servers time (reduce 1h), the task will schedule at 01:01h instead of the servers 00:01h.

If I restart the application it will work just fine. Does anyone know how to update the schedule time if I change the servers time?

Comment: Why are you changing the time on your server? Time should be taken from the global clock (ntp). Many application's correct operation depends on a correct system clock.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, the server does not have internet access, or access to a NTP server

Comment: Still, why do you change the server time? Why not keep it at the same time, as best matching UTC as you possibly can, as it is supposed to be?